# How to make fluffy Appam without Sweet?

Tags: fermentation, batter

I have seen all recipies of Appam that use sugar for fermenting. How can I make salty tasting fluffy white appam ? I have wasted around 3 kgs of rice trying it but, still unsuccessful.

Comment: Hey,  It would be helpful if you added your recipe and method - that is, what kinds of things you have been trying and why they didn't work for you.  It will make it easier for people to figure out what's going on and what might help.